# Could not find or load main class, parent folder?

Tags: java

I have a problem to run my projects in NetBeans.

I think this is some path problems, I fixed it with other project before, but I still confuse with this.

This is the code what I have

```
public class TestStack
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] dblElements = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
        int[] intElements = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

        // Create a staqck of doubles & a stack of ints

        Stack<Double> dStack = new Stack<Double>(5);
        Stack<Integer> iStack = new Stack<Integer>();

        // push elements onto the stack
        PushDouble(dStack, dblElements);
        PopDouble(dStack);

    }

        private static void PushInteger(Stack<Integer> stack, int[] values)
    {
        System.out.println("\nPushing elements onto stack of integers");
        for (int i : values)
        {
            System.out.printf("%.1f ", i);
            stack.push(i);
        }
    }
    private static void PopInteger(Stack<Integer> stack)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("\nPopping elements from stack of integers");
            double value;
            // Remove all elements from stack & display them
            while(true)
            {
                value = stack.pop();
                System.out.printf("%.1f ",value);
            }
        } // end of try block
        catch(EmptyStackException E)
        {
            System.err.println();
            E.printStackTrace();
        } // end of catch block
    }

    private static void PushDouble(Stack<Double> stack, double[] values)
    {
        System.out.println("\nPushing elements onto stack of doubles");
        for (double d : values)
        {
            System.out.printf("%.1f ", d);
            stack.push(d);
        }
    }
    private static void PopDouble(Stack<Double> stack)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("\nPopping elements from stack of doubles");
            double value;
            // Remove all elements from stack & display them
            while(true)
            {
                value = stack.pop();
                System.out.printf("%.1f ",value);
            }
        } // end of try block
        catch(EmptyStackException E)
        {
            System.err.println();
            E.printStackTrace();
        } // end of catch block
    }
}
```

And my error is...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class teststack.TestStack
```

What should I do?

Comment: How are you running the program?  From within Netbeans or from the command line?

Comment: It sounds like you've recently moved the main class.  Right click the main project's node and select "Properties".  Select "Run" from the "Categories".  There is a option called "Main Class", select "Browse..." and select the `TestStack` class from the available list.  Click "Ok", build and run...

Comment: That's what I did... Ye, I really don't know what is going on here.

Comment: Did you try a clean and build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message, your `TestStack` class is in the `teststack` package.  Therefore, the file "TestStack.java" must reside in a folder called `teststack` under the main folder, not in the main folder itself.

Comment: Do you mean I have to create one folder inside my teststack folder?

Comment: No, just ensure that TestStack.java is in the teststack folder.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class TestStack is placed under the directory teststack as you are using that as a package. Compile and run like this:

```
javac teststack/TestStack.java
java teststack.TestStack
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've selected wrong main class. Try right clicking on your project in NetBeans, select Properties, in Categories select Run and then select TestStack class as Main class.